# How to display single post in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

I'm trying to make a blog site using MERN stack. So here I have my Article component which fetches
the single post by id the router is worked but doesn't show  any content on an article page

Article.js
I have a problem with this page doesn't show the single post

```js
    import React ,{useState,useEffect}from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default function Article(_id) {
      const [title,setTitle]=useState("");
      const [content,setContent]=useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
        .get(`http://localhost:5000/article/${_id}`)
          .then((res => [
            setTitle(res.data.title),
            setContent(res.data.content),
          ]))
          .catch(error=>console.log(error))
        }, []);   
        
        // const mapOverArticle=article.map((articleObj,i)=>{
        //   return <p>{articleObj.title}</p>
        // })
      return (
      <div>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <p className="card-text">{content}</p>
      </div>
      )
      }
```

App.js

```js
((postObj,i)=>
     <Post
      key={i}
      posts={postObj}
      deletePost={deletePost}
      editPost={editPost}
      />);
      return (
      <div className=' App'>   
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={
        <div className='Home'>
        {mapOverPosts}
        </div>
        } />
        <Route  path="/article/:id"  element={<Article />}/>
        </Routes>
```

Post.js
This page show all posts on my blog

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
// import axios from 'axios';
export default function Post(props) {
   const{_id,title,content}=props.posts;
    return (
<div className='Post container'>
<div className='row'>
<div className="card ms-20" style={{width: "40rem"}}  >
  <div className="card-body">
    <form>
      <Link to={{pathname:`/article/${_id}`}}>
    <h5 type="text" className="card-title">{title}</h5>
    </Link>
    <p className="card-text">{content}</p>
    </form>

    {/* <Link to ="/article">readmore</Link> */}
    <button
                onClick={() => {
                  props.deletePost(_id);
                }}
                className="btn btn-outline-danger"
             >Delete</button>

            <button
                onClick={() => {
                  props.editPost(_id);
                }}
                className="btn btn-outline-info"
             >Edit</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>     
</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since the _id is a prop you have to destructure it like this

```
export default function Article({_id})
```

or you can do it like this

```
export default function Article(props) {
  const [title,setTitle]=useState("");
  const [content,setContent]=useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    axios
    .get(`http://localhost:5000/article/${props._id}`) // you can access it like this
      .then((res => [
        setTitle(res.data.title),
        setContent(res.data.content),
      ]))
      .catch(error=>console.log(error))
    }, []);   
    
    // const mapOverArticle=article.map((articleObj,i)=>{
    //   return <p>{articleObj.title}</p>
    // })
  return (
  <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p className="card-text">{content}</p>
  </div>
  )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    export default function Article(props) {
      const [title,setTitle]=useState("");
      const [content,setContent]=useState("");
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
        .get(`http://localhost:5000/article/${props._id}`) // you can access it like this
          .then((res => [
            setTitle(res.data.title),
            setContent(res.data.content),
          ]))
          .catch(error=>console.log(error))
        }, []);   
        
        // const mapOverArticle=article.map((articleObj,i)=>{
        //   return <p>{articleObj.title}</p>
        // })
      return (
      <div>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <p className="card-text">{content}</p>
      </div>
      )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I made some modifications to the code to suit the version of router dom 6 and the code worked:)**

```
import React ,{useState,useEffect}from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
export default function Article(props) {
  const [title,setTitle]=useState("");
  const [content,setContent]=useState("");
const params =useParams();
console.log({props,params});
useEffect(() => {
    axios
    .get(`http://localhost:5000/article/${params.id}`) // you can access it like this
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("DATA: ", res.data);
        setTitle(res.data.title);
        console.log(res.data.title);
        setContent(res.data.content);
      })
      .catch(error=>console.log(error))
    }, [props])
  return (
  <div>
<h1>{title}</h1>
<p>{content}</p>
  </div>
  )
}
```